# How to pass and show data to the popup window when click on the each node using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, binary-tree, popupwindow

I want to show a pop-up window on this binary tree view and when clicking on each node I need to show details on the node using ajax. I only need javascript and ajax code for how to pass data to the popup window. I already wrote some code but not sure if it's correct. I'm seeking for a solution.My popup window code is attached in here and Check the diagram for how the view should be. If any further question let me know. Thank you.
[image: Tree diagram with popup model]

```css
html,body,div,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,ol,ul,li,form,fieldset,legend,label,table,header,footer,nav,section,figure
{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html
{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
body
{
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  line-height:1.6;
  color:#5A6064;
}
pre,code
{
  tab-size:4;
}
p
{
  margin:0 0 11px;
}
ul
{
  list-style:disc;
}
ul,ol
{
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 11px 25px;
}
li
{
  line-height:22px;
  margin:0 0 .5em;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
{
  margin:0;
  font-weight:400;
  text-rendering:optimizelegibility;
  color:#282B30;
  font-family:Calibri,"PT Sans","Trebuchet MS",'Helvetica Neue',Arial
}

.gc3
{
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  padding:1em;
  overflow:hidden
}
.grid-c .gc3:nth-of-type(2n+1)
{
  clear:left
}
#logo
{
  height:150px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;width:100%;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  padding:0 3em;
  margin-left:-3em;
  cursor:pointer;
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-bottom:50px
  }
  #broken-glass
  {
    height:100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%
  }
  #logo:active h1
  {
    top:1px
  }
  #logo h1
  {
    margin-top:27px;
    font-size:63px;
    line-height:1.4;
    top:0
  }
  #logo h1
  {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:700;
    width:100%;
    color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  h2.intro
  {
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:1.2;
    font-weight:400;
    border:0;
    margin-top:0;
  }
  #header-links
  {
    font-size:16px;
  }
  
    #main-wrapper
    {
      background:0;
      max-width:800px;
      width:100%;
      margin:2em auto 4em;
      padding:3em;
      padding-top:0;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      position:relative;
    }
    .white-popup-block
    {
      background:#FFF;
      padding:20px 30px;
      text-align:left;
      max-width:650px;
      margin:40px auto;
      position:relative;
    }
   
      #logo-overlay
      {
        width:100%;
        height:75px;
      }
      #logo-overlay
      {
        opacity:1;
        background:red;
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        opacity:0;
      }
      #mfp-build-tool
      {
        background:#FFF;
        padding:30px 40px 40px;
        max-width:500px;text-align:left;
        margin:10px auto;
        position:relative;
        }
      .il
      {
        color:#099;
      }
      .mfp-bg
      {
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:1042;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:fixed;
        background:#0b0b0b;
        opacity:.8;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80);
        }
      .mfp-wrap
      {
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        z-index:1043;
        position:fixed;
        outline:0!important;
        -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
      }
      .mfp-container
      {
        text-align:center;
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        left:0;
        top:0;
        padding:0 8px;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .mfp-container:before
        {
          content:'';
          display:inline-block;
          height:100%;
          vertical-align:middle;
        }
        .mfp-align-top .mfp-container:before
        {
          display:none;
        }
        .mfp-content
        {
          position:relative;
          display:inline-block;
          vertical-align:middle;
          margin:0 auto;
          text-align:left;
          z-index:1045;
        }
        .mfp-inline-holder .mfp-content,.mfp-ajax-holder .mfp-content
        {
          width:100%;
          cursor:auto;
        }
        .mfp-ajax-cur
        {
          cursor:progress;
        }
        .mfp-zoom-out-cur,.mfp-zoom-out-cur .mfp-image-holder .mfp-close
        {
          cursor:-moz-zoom-out;
          cursor:-webkit-zoom-out;
          cursor:zoom-out;
        }
        .mfp-zoom
        {
          cursor:pointer;
          cursor:-webkit-zoom-in;
          cursor:-moz-zoom-in;
          cursor:zoom-in;
        }
        .mfp-auto-cursor .mfp-content
        {
          cursor:auto;
        }
        .mfp-close,.mfp-arrow,.mfp-preloader,.mfp-counter
        {
          -webkit-user-select:none;
          -moz-user-select:none;
          user-select:none;
        }
        .mfp-loading.mfp-figure
        {
          display:none;
        }
        .mfp-hide
        {
          display:none!important;
        }
        .mfp-preloader
        {
          color:#ccc;
          position:absolute;
          top:50%;
          width:auto;
          text-align:center;
          margin-top:-.8em;
          left:8px;
          right:8px;
          z-index:1044;
        }
        .mfp-preloader a
        {
          color:#ccc;
        }
        .mfp-preloader a:hover
        {
          color:#fff;
        }
        .mfp-s-ready .mfp-preloader
        {
          display:none;
        }
        .mfp-s-error .mfp-content
        {
          display:none;
        }
        button.mfp-close,button.mfp-arrow
        {
          overflow:visible;
          cursor:pointer;
          background:transparent;
          border:0;
          -webkit-appearance:none;
          display:block;
          outline:0;
          padding:0;
          z-index:1046;
          -webkit-box-shadow:none;
          box-shadow:none;
        }
        button::-moz-focus-inner
        {
          padding:0;
          border:0;
        }
        .mfp-close
        {
          width:44px;
          height:44px;
          line-height:44px;
          position:absolute;
          right:0;
          top:0;
          text-decoration:none;
          text-align:center;
          opacity:.65;
          padding:0 0 18px 10px;
          color:#fff;
          font-style:normal;
          font-size:28px;
          font-family:Arial,Baskerville,monospace;
        }
        .mfp-close:hover,.mfp-close:focus
        {
          opacity:1;
        }
        .mfp-close:active
        {
          top:1px;
        }
        .mfp-close-btn-in .mfp-close
        {
          color:#333;
        }
```

```html
<body>

  
    <div class="example gc3">
    <h3>Popup For Details</h3>
    <div class="html-code">
      <!-- link that opens popup -->
      <a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">Click Here</a>

      <!-- form itself -->
      <form id="test-form" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
        <h1>Details</h1>
        <fieldset style="border:0;">
          
          <ol>
            <li>
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" required>
            </li>
            <li>
              <label for="ID">Id No</label>
              <input id="ID" name="ID" type="ID" placeholder="Eg. 0001" required>
            </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
          type: 'inline',
          preloader: false,
          focus: '#name',

         
          callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function() {
              if($(window).width() < 700) {
                this.st.focus = false;
              } else {
                this.st.focus = '#name';
              }
            }
          }
        });
      });


$(document).ready(function() {

        $('.simple-ajax-popup-align-top').magnificPopup({
          type: 'ajax',
          alignTop: true,
          overflowY: 'scroll'
        });

        $('.simple-ajax-popup').magnificPopup({
          type: 'ajax'
        });

$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:
          data:{name:$("#name_new").val(),Email:$("#email_new").val(),ID:$("ID_new").val()},
          success: function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('div.success').fadeIn();
          }
          
       }
        
      });

    </script>
  </body>
```

`enter code here`

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for instructions

Comment: actually where  is you found error?make a click event ,when click in a tree element it pass id then fetch name , email and id from db then show model

Comment: I need some code for it.